# Can zargs run aliases?

Tags: zsh, xargs

I have `pip install -U` aliased as `pi`. I want to run:

```
zargs ~/scripts/python/**/requirements.txt -- pi -r
```

Is there any way to do this?

I also tried this ugly alternative:

```
zargs ~/scripts/python/**/requirements.txt -- ${aliases[pi]} -r
```

But it said `(eval):2: command not found: pip install -U`.

I imagined zargs should be able to do exactly these kinds of stuff, since it is a zsh builtin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are `csh`'s poor man's functions. The aliases are not really commands, they are more text substitutions. `alias`es have their use in more advanced shells that do have functions, as hacking tools for cases where functions can't be used, like in things like:

```
alias forever='while true; do'
```

Or

```
alias fail='{ echo >&2 FAIL; return 1; }'
```

Which wouldn't work with functions. But here, it's not one of those cases.

```
alias pi='pip install -U'
```

Doesn't define a `pi` *command*, it defines a `pi` *alias*. Here, as it happens, upon expansion, that ends up being turned into the start of a simple command, but aliased are not expanded in all cases where a command is expected. In particular, they are not expanded within functions like `zargs` here (well, they are, but at the time of the function *definition*, not invocation, that's were our `forever` or `fail` aliases above can be useful). And they are expanded in some contexts where not appropriate (like in `pi() { ...; }`).

A global alias is not a solution, global aliases are still not commands, they'll still text substitution, but expanded in even more cases.

After a

```
alias -g pi='pip install -U'
```

Now, a `pi` word is expanded wherever it occurs. So for instance, `echo pi` would output `pip install -U`.

Here, if you wanted to define a `pi` command, you would use a function:

```
pi() pip install -U "$@"
```

That one would be invoked by `zargs`.

With your `pi` *simple* alias, you could still do:

```
zargs ~/scripts/python/**/requirements.txt -- ${=aliases[pi]} -r
```

That is, invoke `$IFS`-splitting on the definition of the alias. Or going a bit further:

```
zargs ~/scripts/python/**/requirements.txt -- "${(@Q)${(ze)aliases[pi]}}" -r
```

where `z` does the splitting while taking into account quoting (so for instance `echo "foo bar"` be split into `echo` and `"foo bar"` instead of `echo`, `"foo` and `bar"`), `e` to perform expansions (like `echo $(uname)` expanded to `echo Linux` for instance), `Q` to remove the quotes, which would give a better approximation in a few more cases.

Comment: But isn't an alias faster than a function?

Comment: @HappyFace, not in any significant way, they are two different features, and are both internal to the shell.